# Whenever I try to install a new python package getting error

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

When I run pip install selenium on cmd it gives this error

```
C:\Users\Shaharyar Parekh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>pip install selenium
Collecting selenium
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x06455C30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))': /simple/selenium/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x06455DF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))': /simple/selenium/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x06455CF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))': /simple/selenium/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x06455BF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))': /simple/selenium/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x06455D70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))': /simple/selenium/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for selenium
```

I tried to reinstall python interpretor several times but it didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a wrong proxy address and port entered in my proxy settings. That's why this error was continuously poping

Comment: I solved this case by set  proxy, https://kb.k12usa.com/knowledgebase/proxy-settings-on-a-mac-os-x